# How can I add boxes to shiny app without ruining page?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have a shiny app that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to add a Box 3 and Box 4 beneath the mouse logo, but cannot seem to figure out how to do this without messing the page up. The result is below:

[image]

i am using two `fluidRow` functions to make these boxes, but I am not sure how I can keep the entire page intact while doing so. Any help is appreciated! Code is below:

```
#require packages
 rqrd_Pkg = c('shiny','plotly','plyr','tidyverse',
         'uuid', 'devtools', 'gtools', 'inline', 'shiny',
         'shinydashboard', 'plotly', 'shinythemes',
         'shinycssloaders', 'shinyjs', 
         'DT', 'tictoc',
         'data.table', 'htmlwidgets')

  require(shiny)
  for(p in rqrd_Pkg){
    if(!require(p,character.only = TRUE)) 
      install.packages(p, Ncpus=8);
      library(p,character.only = TRUE)
}


#include style for header
head.style <- "
         /* old shiny progress indicators */
         .shiny-progress-container {
           position: fixed;
           top: 0px;
           width: 100%;
           z-index: 4000;
     }
     .shiny-progress .progress-text {
       color: #020202;
       background-colort: #FF0000;
       width: 225px;
       left: calc(50% - 125px);
     }
     .progress-text {
       /* Copy the below to vertically center the progress bar text box in the shiny dashboard header */
       /* !important is crucial here otherwise it gets overridden by the dreaded element.style */
       top: 15px !important;
       text-align: center;
     }
     "  

#initiate dashboard attributes and colors
dashboardPage(
    skin = "purple",

    dashboardHeader(
    title = HTML("Title"),
    dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",  icon = tagList(icon("question-circle"), "Help"),  badgeStatus = NULL,  headerText = "Links",
                 tags$li(a(icon("external-link"),  "XYZ",  href = "http://info.com", target = "blank")),
                 tags$li(a(icon("external-link"),  "ABC", href = "http://info.com", target = "blank")))
),

dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Target Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard_tab", icon = icon("dashboard"))
)),

#################################################################################  
#################################################################################  
#################################################################################  
#################################################################################  

#Configure dashboard body. 
dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
        tags$link(rel = "shortcut icon", href = "favicon.ico"),
        tags$link(rel = "apple-touch-icon", sizes = "180x180", href = "favicon.ico"),
        tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/png", sizes = "32x32", href = "favicon-32x32.png"),
        tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/png", sizes = "16x16", href = "favicon-16x16.png"),
        tags$style(head.style)
    ),
    
    
    #h1(paste0("<b>","Gene summary:","</b>")),
    titlePanel(div(HTML("<b>Gene summary</b>"), align = "left")),
    
    
    tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard_tab",
                 tags$style(HTML("
                  #first {
                      border: 4px double red;
                  }
                  #second {
                      border: 2px dashed blue;
                  }
                ")),
                fluidRow(
                  valueBoxOutput("valueGeneName"),
                  valueBoxOutput("valueGeneRank"),
                  valueBoxOutput("gtexSpec"),
                  valueBoxOutput("valueHuman"),
                  valueBoxOutput("valueMouse"),
                  valueBoxOutput("valueNHP"),
                  valueBoxOutput("exprCompartment")
                ),
                
                h2(paste0("Header 1"), align="left"),
                
                #insert human logo
                mainPanel(
                  img(src='man_log.png', height="10%", width="10%", align="left"),
                ),
                
                
                #create boxes
                fluidRow( 
                    box(
                        title = "Box 1",
                        status = "primary",
                        solidHeader = TRUE,
                        collapsible = TRUE,
                        plotOutput("roc", height = "300px")
                    ),
                    box(
                        title = "Box 2"
                        ,status = "primary"
                        ,solidHeader = TRUE
                        ,collapsible = TRUE
                        ,plotOutput("sensDNAProt", height = "300px")
                    )), 
                mainPanel(
                  img(src='mouse.png', height="10%", width="10%", align="left")
                ),
                
                h2(paste0("Header 2"), align="left"),
                

                #ADDING THIS CAUSES PROBLEMS!!!
                fluidRow(
                  box(
                    title = "Box 3",
                    status = "primary",
                    solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = TRUE,
                    plotOutput("roc", height = "300px")
                  ), 
                  box(
                    title = "Box 4",
                    status = "primary",
                    solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = TRUE,
                    plotOutput("roc", height = "300px")
                  )
                )
        )
    )      
)
```

)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the desired output with this.

```
### include style for header
head.style <- "
         /* old shiny progress indicators */
         .shiny-progress-container {
           position: fixed;
           top: 0px;
           width: 100%;
           z-index: 4000;
     }
     .shiny-progress .progress-text {
       color: #020202;
       background-colort: #FF0000;
       width: 225px;
       left: calc(50% - 125px);
     }
     .progress-text {
       /* Copy the below to vertically center the progress bar text box in the shiny dashboard header */
       /* !important is crucial here otherwise it gets overridden by the dreaded element.style */
       top: 15px !important;
       text-align: center;
     }
     "

#initiate dashboard attributes and colors
ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "purple",

  dashboardHeader(
    title = HTML("Title"),
    dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",  icon = tagList(icon("question-circle"), "Help"),  badgeStatus = NULL,  headerText = "Links",
                 tags$li(a(icon("external-link"),  "XYZ",  href = "http://info.com", target = "blank")),
                 tags$li(a(icon("external-link"),  "ABC", href = "http://info.com", target = "blank")))
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Target Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard_tab", icon = icon("dashboard"))
  )),

  #################################################################################
  #################################################################################
  #################################################################################
  #################################################################################

  #Configure dashboard body.
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "shortcut icon", href = "favicon.ico"),
      tags$link(rel = "apple-touch-icon", sizes = "180x180", href = "favicon.ico"),
      tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/png", sizes = "32x32", href = "favicon-32x32.png"),
      tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/png", sizes = "16x16", href = "favicon-16x16.png"),
      tags$style(head.style)
    ),


    #h1(paste0("<b>","Gene summary:","</b>")),
    titlePanel(div(HTML("<b>Gene summary</b>"), align = "left")),

    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard_tab",
              tags$style(HTML("
                  #first {
                      border: 4px double red;
                  }
                  #second {
                      border: 2px dashed blue;
                  }
                ")),
              
              fluidRow(width=12,
                tabBox(id = "tabset1", height = "2250px", width=12, title = " ",
                  tabPanel(
                    br(),br(),
                    fluidRow(h2(paste0("Header 0"), align="left")),
                    fluidRow(
                      shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput("myvaluebox1", width=4),
                      shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput("myvaluebox2", width=4),
                      shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput("myvaluebox3", width=4)
                    ),
                    fluidRow(
                      shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput("myvaluebox4", width=4),
                      shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput("myvaluebox5", width=4),
                      shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput("myvaluebox6", width=4)
                    ),
                    fluidRow(
                      shinydashboard::infoBoxOutput("myvaluebox7", width=4),
                      shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput("myvaluebox8", width=4)
                    ),
                    br(),
                    fluidRow(h2(paste0("Header 1"), align="left")),
                    #br(),
                    fluidRow(img(src='man_log.png', height="5%", width="5%", align="left")),
                    br(),
                    fluidRow(
                      column(6,
                             box( height="300px",  width=NULL,
                                  collapsible = TRUE,
                                  title = "Box 1",
                                  status = "primary",
                                  solidHeader = TRUE,
                                  plotOutput("plot1", height = "210px", width="350px")
                             ),  style='width: 500px; height: 400px' ),
                      column(6,
                             box(height="300px", width="450px",
                                 title = "Box 2",
                                 status = "primary",
                                 solidHeader = TRUE,
                                 collapsible = TRUE,
                                 plotOutput("plot2", height = "230px", width="380px")
                             ),  style='width: 500px; height: 400px') 
                    ),
                    br(),# br(),
                    img(src='mouse.png', height="10%", width="10%", align="left"),
                    br(),
                    h2(paste0("Header 2"), align="left"),
                    br(),
                    fluidRow(
                      column(6,
                             box(height="300px", width="450px",
                                 title = "Box 3",
                                 status = "primary",
                                 solidHeader = TRUE,
                                 collapsible = TRUE,
                                 plotOutput("plot3", height = "220px", width="350px")
                             ),  style='width: 500px; height: 400px' ),
                      column(6,
                             box(height="300px", width="450px",
                                 title = "Box 4",
                                 status = "primary",
                                 solidHeader = TRUE,
                                 collapsible = TRUE,
                                 plotOutput("plot4", height = "220px", width="350px")
                             ),  style='width: 500px; height: 400px')
                    )
                  )  ## end of tabPanel

                  )  ## end of tabBox
                ) 

              )  ## end of tabItem
            
      )
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph1"))
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("green"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph2"))
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph3"))
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("orange"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph4"))

  output$myvaluebox1 <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox('2000',subtitle = "blah blah blah1",icon = icon("car"),
               color = "green"
    )
  })
  output$myvaluebox2 <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox('2001',subtitle = "blah blah blah2",icon = icon("car"),
               color = "green"
    )
  })
  output$myvaluebox3 <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox('2002',subtitle = "blah blah blah3",icon = icon("car"),
               color = "green"
    )
  })
  output$myvaluebox4 <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox('2009',subtitle = "blah blah blah4",icon = icon("car"),
               color = "red"
    )
  })
  output$myvaluebox5 <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox('2010',subtitle = "XYZ1",icon = icon("car"),
               color = "red"
    )
  })
  output$myvaluebox6 <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox('2011',subtitle = "XYZ2",icon = icon("car"),
               color = "green"
    )
  })
  output$myvaluebox7 <- shinydashboard::renderInfoBox({
    shinydashboard::infoBox('2020',subtitle = "This is infobox",icon = icon("car"),
               color = "blue"
    )
  })
  output$myvaluebox8 <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox('2021',subtitle = "This is valuebox",icon = icon("car"),
               color = "blue"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much. This is great.